# ConvertTo-Json fails to convert custom properties added to built-in types

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to a add a custom property to a built-in PowerShell type and then convert the object to Json.  The problem I'm running into is that the ConvertTo-Json will not convert the custom property I'm adding.  For example,

```
$Proc = Get-Process explorer
$Proc.Modules | %{
    $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty MyCustomProperty "123456" -PassThru
}

$Proc.Modules[0].MyCustomProperty -eq "123456"    
# Returns true

$Json = ConvertTo-Json ($Proc.Modules) -Depth 4
$Json -match "123456"   
# Returns false.  Expect it to be true
```

Edit: If I use "select *" with ConvertTo-Json, then it works. E.g.

```
$Json = ConvertTo-Json ($Proc.Modules | select *) -Depth 4
$Json -match "123456"   
# Returns true
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: PowerShell v2 does not include `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet. If you use some custom implementation, then you should specify which one.

Comment: Fixed. Issue still occurs on all versions of PS >= 3.0

Comment: It happens, that `ConvertTo-Json` looks into custom properties only when it see `PSObject`.

Comment: Then why does the output of "$Procs[40].Modules[0] | ConvertTo-Json" contain the custom property?

Comment: PowerShell wrap items into `PSObject` when pass them by pipeline.

Comment: @PetSerAl, have you been decompiling again? I can't find anything (on MSDN) about how and where this cmdlet converts known types to JSON. Also, if you have a link explaining how the customized object is "wrapped" when passed through the pipeline I'd love to read up on that.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Yes, I use ILSpy to look into `ConvertTo-Json` behavior. And about wrapping, not sure what you want to see, it is just experimental fact: `function f { param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][Object]$InputObject) [Type]::GetTypeArray((,$InputObject)) }; [object]::new() | f; f ([object]::new())` — first call to `f` will print that you have `PSObject`, while second print `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `ConvertTo-Json` look into extended properties only when it sees `PSObject` instance. If you pass unwrapped object, then only base object properties will get into resulting JSON:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    public class SomeType {
        public static SomeType NewInstanceWithExtendedProperty() {
            SomeType instance = new SomeType();
            PSObject.AsPSObject(instance).Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty("ExtendedProperty", "ExtendedValue"));
            return instance;
        }
        public string SomeProperty {
            get {
                return "SomeValue";
            }
        }

    }
'@
$a=[SomeType]::NewInstanceWithExtendedProperty()
ConvertTo-Json ($a, [PSObject]$a)
```

This code will return:

```
[
    {
        "SomeProperty":  "SomeValue"
    },
    {
        "SomeProperty":  "SomeValue",
        "ExtendedProperty":  "ExtendedValue"
    }
]
```

As you can see, `ExtendedProperty` get into JSON only when you explicitly cast `$a` to `PSObject`.